# How do I select an option using prototype

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

Say I have a HTML form containing this select element:

```
  <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect">
    <option value="1" id="option1">1</option>
    <option value="2" id="option2">2</option>
  </select>
```

How can I use prototype to select one of the option elements?

The methods listed in [the API reference of Form.Element](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/form/element) don't seem to help with this.

edit: by "select" I mean the equivalent effect of the "selected" attribute on an option element.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
var options = $$('select#mySelect option');
var len = options.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    console.log('Option text = ' + options[i].text);
    console.log('Option value = ' + options[i].value);
}
```

`options` is an array of all option elements in `#mySelect` dropdown. If you want to mark one or more of them as selected just use `selected` property

```
// replace 1 with index of an item you want to select
options[1].selected = true;
```

Comment: If you have id's for your all options set then yes, you can do it like that.

Comment: @PatB in Prototype that's how you get elements using CSS selectors, just $ is the same as getElementById().

Answer (score 15):

To get the currently selected option, use:

```
$$('#mySelect option').find(function(ele){return !!ele.selected})
```

Comment: I thought that `.attributes['selected'] = true;` is what I need, but correct code is `.selected = true;`

Comment: Can you just use `$('mySelect').value` to get the value?

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
$('mySelect').setValue(1); // or whatever value you want to select
```

this one would select `option1`

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! And if you want to select an option with the selected value from another select use:

`$('select1').setValue($('select2').getValue())`

Answer (score 8):

nils petersohn almost got it right, but typically, the option's "id" attribute is not what people are selecting against.  this small change makes it work.

```
var selectThis = 'option1';
$$('select#mySelectId option').each(function(o) {
  if(o.readAttribute('value') == selectThis) { // note, this compares strings
    o.selected = true;
    throw $break; // remove this if it's a multi-select
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For selecting the second option by value you could use this:

```
var myChoice = '2';

$$('select#mySelectId option').each(function(o) {
    o.selected = o.readAttribute('value') == myChoice;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var itis = $(mySelectId).select('option[value="' + sValueToSelect + '"]');
if ( itis && itis.length > 0 )
    itis[0].selected = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know what value you want to be selected, try:

```
$('mySelect').value = 2; // 2 being the value you want selected
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectThis = 'option1';
$$('select#mySelect option').each(function(o){
      if(o.id==selectThis){o.selected = true;$break;}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this...

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
   $('mySelect').observe('change', function(event) {
    ...
   });
});
```